# Inline editable table, that can save whole table using submit button bootstrap in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to develop a Razor view page like following , that consist with inline editing, but saving using single submit button.

[image]

So I did up to this level in my Viewpage

```
@model IEnumerable<sample.Models.Sample>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Value)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

How can I continue from here, I'm not planning to use any 3rd party library such as jQuery Datatable,

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use jQuery datatable but why cannot you use basic jQuery. On edit set a dirty attribute for the inline text control and on submit you can make an ajax call using jQuery and pass the data in JSON format to your post method in your controller.

Comment: can you recommend a good example that I can refer, and achieve this